# Proof based on logic

Tags: real-analysis, logic

I have a function $f(x)$ and I want to prove that $x^*>y$ where $x^*$ is the number that satisfies $f'(x^*) =0$ and $y$ is just an arbitrary constant. So what I did is that I assume $x^*>y$ and show second derivative $f"(x^*)|_{x^*>y}<0$, then I show that $f'(y)>0$, representing that $x^*>y$. Thus the first assumption is true and there proof is correct. Is it correct way to do?

Comment: wait, so you prove what you assume?

Comment: Yes I assume what I need to prove..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a function f(x) and I want to prove that x∗>y where x∗ is the number that satisfies f′(x∗)=0 and y is just an arbitrary constant. So what I did is that I assume x∗>y and show second derivative f"(x∗)|x∗>y<0, then I show that f′(y)>0, representing that x∗>y. Thus the first assumption is true and there proof is correct. Is it correct way to do?

Let's take this slowly.  Before you try to prove something, you need to know what it is you are trying to prove, and it seems from how you have worded the question that you don't fully understand the goal of the problem.

> I have a function f(x)

Are you thinking about a *specific* function $f(x)$ -- for example, $f(x)=x^2$ -- or are you trying to prove something that is true about *every* function $f(x)$ that has certain properties?  If you are trying to prove something about a *specific* function, it may be that the proof will depend on the particulars of what the function is, and without telling us what the function is, we may not be able to help you.  On the other hand if you are trying to prove something about *any* function with certain properties, we should at least know what those properties are.

> I want to prove that x∗>y where x∗ is the number that satisfies f′(x∗)=0 and y is just an arbitrary constant.

What do you mean by "an arbitrary constant"?  Taken literally, you seem to be saying that you want to prove that no matter what value of $y$ is chosen, $x^*$ will be greater than $y$.

Before trying to prove that, think about what it says.  It says that $x^*$ is greater than *every real number*.  That's not possible -- no number is greater than every real number.

What I think you mean to be saying is:  "I am looking at a problem that has some specific constant in it, and I want to prove that some other value is greater than that constant."  In order to prove that, we would need to know something about the constant you are interested in.

Let's take a specific example:  Suppose $f(x)=x^2-6x+9$.  Let's choose the "arbitrary constant" to be $y=5$.  Now you can verify for yourself that the only value $x^*$ for which $f'(x^*)=0$ is $x^*=3$.  Then the claim that $x^*>y$ is evidently false, because $3$ is not greater than $5$.

So let's assume that you have a specific function in mind, and a specific constant in mind, and let's suppose that the thing you are trying to prove is actually true, and you are just not telling us the particulars of the problem because you are looking for some kind of general strategies rather than a solution to *this* problem.  Let's take a look at the argument you want to make:

> I assume x∗>y

As others have pointed out, assuming the thing you are trying to prove is a bad idea.  Not just because it's "poor form", but because the moment you make the assumption $x^*>y$, anything else that follows has a big "IF" in front of it: The most you will be able to prove is that "**IF** $x^* > y$ then $x^* > y$".  That's not a particularly useful or meaningful conclusion -- it's like saying "If I eat grilled cheese, then I eat grilled cheese."  It may be true, but it doesn't actually answer the question of what I will have for lunch today.

> and show second derivative f"(x∗)|x∗>y<0

What does the vertical line mean in this context?

What does $x^∗>y<0$ mean?  Stringing inequalities together is meaningful if they point in the same direction, because $ > $ and $ < $ are transitive:  this means that if $a < b$ and $b < c$ then $a < c$ as well, so you can write $ a < b < c$ as a shorthand for "$a < b$ and $b < c$".  But if the inequalities point in different directions (like $a < b > c$ or $a > b < c$) then it isn't clear what the expression is supposed to mean.

Also, why does it matter that $y<0$?  Does this have anything to do with the problem?

> then I show that f′(y)>0, representing that x∗>y

Assuming you have correctly shown that $f'(y)>0$, why does that mean that $x^* > y$ must be true as well?

> Thus the first assumption is true and there proof is correct.

As noted above (and this really cannot be emphasized strongly enough) if you make an assumption and then do a lot of work and then end up deriving the same thing you assumed at the top, then all you have done is prove "If the assumption is true, then the assumption is true."  That does not resolve the question of whether the assumption *is* true.

To sum up:  This line of argument has a lot of problems with it.  I don't think we are going to be able to help you without knowing more of the particulars of the problem -- I think the proof will depend entirely on what the function $f$ and the constant $y$ are.

Comment: Sorry for my peculiar english..First, question state that function $f(x)$ is a continuous $\forall \, x\in [x_1,x_2 ]$ and quadratic function, and we are only interested $x\in[x_1,x_2], \; x_1<x_2$ and $y$ is a given constant. what I should have written $f''(x | x^*>y)<0, \forall  \,x\in[x_1,x_2]$. As this shows that the function is concave and I define $x^*$ is the number that satisfies $f'(x^*)=0$, $f'(y)>0$ represent $x^*>0$.

Comment: Actually I looked at the question again, and I can show that $f''(x)<0\, , \forall \, x\in[x_1,x_2]$ regardless of $x^*>y$ or $x^*<y$; hence I do not need to put any assumption. Then $f'(y)>0$ shows that $x^*>y$. As I did not assume anything, especially, I did not assume that what I want to prove is true, does this proof holds?

Comment: If $f(x)$ is quadratic, and $f''(x)<0$ for all $x$ on a given interval, then you are looking at a downward-pointing parabola.  If $f'(y)>0$ for the given point $y$ then $y$ is indeed to the left of the parabola's axis of symmetry, which means that $x' > y$.  So if you have shown all of those pieces, then yes, the proof seems to be okay.

Comment: The crucial piece of this (which you left out of the original question) is that the function is quadratic and therefore only has one turning point $x^*$.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, never assume what you are trying to prove. It is possible that it makes sense in your mind to assume something and then test to show it is true, but this is not how formal math is done so most instructors wouldn't accept it.

Second, I am a bit confused about what you are trying to show. This is my guess at your problem:

> Let $f(x)$ be a function let $x_0$ be the solution to $f'(x_0)=0$. Show that $x_0<c$ for some constant $c$.

We really need more information here. Id $c$ and $f$ given? Do you know that $f$ is continuous? My guess is that you just want to find the values where $f'$ is $0$ and show that every such $x$ is less than $c$.

Comment: Sorry for a lack of info, yes function $f $and $c$ are given and the function $f$ is continuous. All I need to show. Is that $x^*>c$